# Can't get 2/4 servers run

Tags: server-administration, server

I have four servers with the following settings:

ORport DirPort 
9001   9030 
22     9040 
110    9050 
143    9060

The machines running all as VMs on my private home server. They're not cloned but setted up identically.

Log on server 3 is saying dir and or port are reachable but I can not find it on tor atlas.

Log on server 4 is telling me received "http status code 404 ( not found ) from server" and it seems like I cannot start tor again. Not even a reboot of the VM makes tor write anything in the log again.

Server 1 and 2 are findable at tor atlas and works fine.

Any idea what could have happened?

Comment: all four are using different IPv4 addresses from distinct subnets?

Comment: and also email ports can be filtered frequently, btw

Comment: I think Alexey is right here, you can only run 2 relays per IP address.

Comment: I only have one IP address. Then I have to shut the other two down. Too bad there is no message for that, in the log or so.

Comment: It's enforced by the Directory Authorities, the number is at their discretion.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's sad that it's not in the logs, but it is buried deep in the protocol mechanics. A brief guess is coming out of the [EnforceDistinctSubnets](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#EnforceDistinctSubnets) directive description. To fix the case when you have just a single address use a VPN with unlimited traffic and static IP address like [this](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/) - as far as I remember they used to provide a static address with unlimited speed and traffic. Just set up an OpenVPN connection and use the `tun` interface to bind to.